# sqlalchemy self-referencing many-to-many with "select" as association table

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, self-referencing-table

## Problem description

I'm using sqlalchemy (v1.2) declarative, and I have a simple class `Node` with an id and a label. I would like to build a self-referencing many-to-many relationship where the association table is not a database table, but a dynamic `select` statement. This statement selects from two joined aliases of `Node` and returns rows of the form `(left_id, right_id)`, defining the relationship. The code I have so far works if I access the relationship through an instance object, but when I try to filter by the relationship the joins are messed up.

## The "classical" self-referential many-to-many relation

For reference, let's start with the example from the documentation on [Self-Referential Many-to-Many Relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship), which uses an association table:

```
node_to_node = Table(
    "node_to_node", Base.metadata,
    Column("left_node_id", Integer, ForeignKey("node.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("right_node_id", Integer, ForeignKey("node.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String, unique=True)
    right_nodes = relationship(
        "Node",
        secondary=node_to_node,
        primaryjoin=id == node_to_node.c.left_node_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == node_to_node.c.right_node_id,
        backref="left_nodes"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(id={}, Label={})".format(self.id, self.label)
```

Joining `Node` to itself through this relationship:

```
>>> NodeAlias = aliased(Node)
>>> print(session.query(Node).join(NodeAlias, Node.right_nodes))
SELECT node.id AS node_id, node.label AS node_label 
FROM node JOIN node_to_node AS node_to_node_1 
    ON node.id = node_to_node_1.left_node_id
JOIN node AS node_1
    ON node_1.id = node_to_node_1.right_node_id
```

Everything looks well.

## The many-to-many relation through an association select statement

As an example we implement a relationship `next_two_nodes` which connects a node to the two nodes with `id+1` and `id+2` (if existent). The [complete code](https://pastebin.com/pcTvhYH6) for testing.

Here is a function which generates the select statement for the "dynamic" association table:

```
_next_two_nodes = None
def next_two_nodes_select():
    global _next_two_nodes
    if _next_two_nodes is None:
        _leftside = aliased(Node, name="leftside")
        _rightside = aliased(Node, name="rightside")
        _next_two_nodes = select(
            [_leftside.id.label("left_node_id"),
             _rightside.id.label("right_node_id")]
        ).select_from(
            join(
                _leftside, _rightside,
                or_(
                    _leftside.id + 1 == _rightside.id,
                    _leftside.id + 2 == _rightside.id
                )
            )
        ).alias()
    return _next_two_nodes
```

Note that the function caches the result in a global variable, so that successive calls always return the same object instead of using new aliases. Here is my attempt to use this `select` in a relationship:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String, unique=True)

    next_two_nodes = relationship(
        "Node", secondary=next_two_nodes_select,
        primaryjoin=(lambda: foreign(Node.id) 
                     == remote(next_two_nodes_select().c.left_node_id)),
        secondaryjoin=(lambda: foreign(next_two_nodes_select().c.right_node_id)
                       == remote(Node.id)),
        backref="previous_two_nodes",
        viewonly=True
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(id={}, Label={})".format(self.id, self.label)
```

Some test data:

```
nodes = [
    Node(id=1, label="Node1"),
    Node(id=2, label="Node2"),
    Node(id=3, label="Node3"),
    Node(id=4, label="Node4")
]
session.add_all(nodes)
session.commit()
```

Accessing the relationship through an instance works as expected:

```
>>> node = session.query(Node).filter_by(id=2).one()
>>> node.next_two_nodes
[Node(id=3, Label=Node3), Node(id=4, Label=Node4)]
>>> node.previous_two_nodes
[Node(id=1, Label=Node1)]
```

However, filtering on the relationship does not give the expected result:

```
>>> session.query(Node).join(NodeAlias, Node.next_two_nodes).filter(NodeAlias.id == 3).all()
[Node(id=1, Label=Node1),
 Node(id=2, Label=Node2),
 Node(id=3, Label=Node3),
 Node(id=4, Label=Node4)]
```

I would expect only `Node1` and `Node2` to be returned. And indeed, the SQL statement of the join is wrong:

```
>>> print(session.query(Node).join(NodeAlias, Node.next_two_nodes))
SELECT node.id AS node_id, node.label AS node_label 
FROM node JOIN (SELECT leftside.id AS left_node_id, rightside.id AS right_node_id 
    FROM node AS leftside JOIN node AS rightside
    ON leftside.id + 1 = rightside.id OR leftside.id + 2 = rightside.id) AS anon_1
ON anon_1.left_node_id = anon_1.left_node_id
JOIN node AS node_1 ON anon_1.right_node_id = node_1.id
```

Comparing with the working example above, instead of `ON anon_1.left_node_id = anon_1.left_node_id` it should clearly read `ON node.id = anon_1.left_node_id`. My `primaryjoin` seems to be wrong, but I cannot figure out how to connect the last dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more debugging I found that ["Clause Adaption"](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2008/01/23/expression-transformations/) is replacing my ON clause. I'm not sure about the details, but for some reasen sqlalchemy thinks that I am referring to the `node.id` from the `select` rather than from the original `Node` table. The only way I found to suppress clause adaption was to select in text form:

```
select(
    [literal_column("leftside.id").label("left_node_id"),
     literal_column("rightside.id").label("right_node_id")]
)...
```

This way the relationship to `Node` is broken and filtering works as expected. It feels like a hack with unforeseeable side effects, maybe someone knows a cleaner way...